# for loop statement and a message box

Tags: vb.net

i'm having problems on how to display continuously with for loop statement, what i want it to display with be data1, data2, data3, data4 and so on with a comma and single space on each value. here's what i do :

```
    Dim str
    For i = 0 To FuelPrice.Items.Count - 1
        str = FuelPrice.Items(i).SubItems(0).Text
        MsgBox(str & ", ")
    Next
```

but i did not get what i expect..lol sorry for the noob question though for i am just totally a noob..lol thanks in advance

Comment: Try `str &= FuelPrice.Items(i).SubItems(0).Text`

Comment: i'll try it..tnx for reponse :D

Answer (score 0):

Use a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.StringBuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to accumulate your text in a single buffer and then display it outside the loop

```
Dim str as StringBuilder = new StringBuilder()

For i = 0 To FuelPrice.Items.Count - 1
    str.Append(FuelPrice.Items(i).SubItems(0).Text & ", ")
Next

' To remove the comma added at the end
if str.Length > 0 then 
   str.Length -= 1
End If
MsgBox(str.ToString())
```

Comment: i got it goin now..but thanks for the response though..cheers :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a generic list (or an array if you prefer), then concatenate the result together.  I think this code is cleaner.

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic    ' If not already referenced

Dim str As New List(Of String)

For i = 0 To FuelPrice.Items.Count - 1
    str.Add(FuelPrice.Items(i).SubItems(0).Text)
Next

MsgBox(String.Join(", ", str))
```